# BatchedTooManyRowsAffectedException for Map

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm having the following issue when I try to store an entity which includes a map.

This is how my Entity looks like:

```
public Class MyEntity {
   private Map<EnumType, MyEmbedabble> map;
   .....
```

This is the relevant part in the orm.xml file:

```
<element-collection name="map" target-class="my.package.MyEmbedabble">
            <map-key-enumerated>STRING</map-key-enumerated>
            <map-key-column name="map_key"/>
            <collection-table>
                <join-column name="entityId"/>
            </collection-table>
 </element-collection>
```

When I store an entity object it works just fine but I noticed that when I store that object again the entries in the table for the element-collection appear multiple times. Once this happened and I try to edit and save an existing map entry I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchedTooManyRowsAffectedException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 5; expected: 1
at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:89)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:73)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:57)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.BasicCollectionPersister.doUpdateRows(BasicCollectionPersister.java:258)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.updateRows(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1630)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionUpdateAction.execute(CollectionUpdateAction.java:85)
```

I highly appreciate any input on this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. In my case, I was using an entity which updated records in another table (I had a one to many relation - one "primary" object with a list of "secondary" objects from a separate table). The settings I had in place were trying to update the other table. This worked fine on create and update methods, but when I attempted to delete an object, I got the `BatchedTooManyRowsAffectedException` exception. I ended up deleting the joined entries and putting them as part of a separate entity.

In your case, I'd suggest taking another look at the settings for the MyEmbeddable map, specifically the part where you set a join column. If your update attempts to remove multiple entries (and therefore multiple rows), that may be the source of the problem.

Look at some of the available XML tags for your definition - you may need something like a one-to-many tag in there somewhere. Unfortunately my experience with entities uses Spring/Hibernate to bypass the need for explicit XML files, so I can't provide any further advice in that regard.

Comment: Thanks, I tried for quite some time to change join and order columns without any success. I also changed my hashCode and equals methods. Now I ended up using separate entities taking advantage of cascade which allows kind of the same behavior. It works for me here but I still don't really understand the issue.